# Jenkins Pipeline deleteDir() is not waiting till the directory has been deleted

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, delete-directory

In my pipeline I have deleteDir() following by git clone. My repo is bit big and have a problem when I rerun the Jenkins pipeline, because deleteDir() is not waiting till the directory has been deleted completely resulting git clone failure. Here is my pippeline

```
node{
    stage ("Clean"){
        dir("${Service}") {
            deleteDir()
        }
    }
    stage ('Checkout'){
        withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'abc', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
            bat "git clone --recurse-submodules http://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@X.X.X.X:9999/scm/x/${Service}.git"
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest me how I can make clone task to wait till deleteDir() iscompleted

Comment: Wonder why you want to remove the whole directory when you could do a git clean. Also wonder why not using the checkout step instead of calling the git cmdline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try to delete the directory in a shell:

```
sh "rm -rf dirName"
```

Answer (score 2):

please make a comment, I do not have enough rating. In Jenkins issues there are many [tickets](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41894?jql=text%20%7E%20%22deletedir%22) related to `deleteDir()`. So [@Frankenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061094/jenkins-pipeline-deletedir-is-not-waiting-till-the-directory-has-been-deleted/49078627#49078627) solution is a good workaround.